# Trying to embed a 159 KB Visio document into PowerPoint: the latter complains it doesn't have enough memory to complete the operation

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-visio-2013, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I am trying to embed a Microsoft Visio 2013 document into a Microsoft PowerPoint 2013 slide.  I use the following:

[image]

I get the error message:

[image]

I have over 8 GB of physical memory available. The Microsoft Visio 2013 document I am trying to embed is 159 KB (you can download it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3pvth9eqepkkh7p/feature_aggregation.vsdx?dl=0)). The Microsoft PowerPoint 2013 document where I am trying to insert the Visio document is just a blank slide. When monitoring the physical memory in use when trying to embed the Microsoft is a document I see a couple of MB being taken but no more.

I use Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013 with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. Any idea what can cause the issue and whether there is any way around (put aside exporting the Microsoft Visio document to some image file)?

The Microsoft Visio looks like:

[image]

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.